# Combinatorial proof of the identity relating Hurwitz numbers

Tags: combinatorics, symmetric-groups, combinatorial-proofs, algebraic-combinatorics

Let define $H^{m}((n);\mu)$ count the number of tuples $(\alpha,\tau_1,\ldots,\tau_r ,\beta)$  in symmetric group $S_n$ where $\alpha$ is fixed cycle of type $(n)$ and $\beta$ cycle of type $\mu$ and

1) r = len($\mu$)-1 where len() imply length of partition.

2) $$\alpha \tau_1\ldots \tau_r =\beta$$

3) $\tau_i$ are transposition written as $(a_i , b_i)$ such that 
 $$ b_1\leq b_2\leq\ldots \leq b_r. $$

Similarly, let's define $H^{sm}((n);\mu)$ to be the number of tuples 
$(\alpha,\tau_1,\ldots,\tau_r ,\beta)$ satisfying all the above condition except $3)$ which is replaced by

3') $\tau_i$ are transposition written as $(a_i , b_i)$ such that 
 $$ b_1< b_2<\ldots <b_r. $$

Let us list few numbers 
$$H^{m}((2),2)=1,\, H^m ((2),(1,1))=1,\, H^m((3),(1,1,1))=2,\, H^m ((3),(2,1))=3,\, H^m ((4),(1,1,1,1))=5,\, H^m ((4),(2,1,1))=10 $$

$$H^{sm}((2),(1,1))=0,\, H^{sm}((2),(2))=1, H((3),(1,1,1))=1,\,  H^{sm}((3),(1,1,1))=1,\,  H^{sm}((3),(2,1))=3,\,  H^{sm}((4),(2,1,1))=6 $$

Let us define two more objects which are the weighted sum of the numbers $H^{m}((n),\nu)$ and $H^{sm}((n),\mu)$ which will form main part of our questions.

$$H^{m}((n);x)=\sum_{\nu\vdash n}H^{m}((n);\nu)x^{-len(\nu)}. $$

$$H^{sm}((n);x)=\sum_{\nu\vdash n}H^{sm}((n);\nu)x^{-len(\nu)}. $$

We have proved the following equation

$$x^{n+1} H^{m}((n+1);x)= (x+1)^{n+1} H^{sm}((n);x+1)  (*)$$

I made some following progress about the proof of (*) but still did not complete it. 
So if we expand both side of the equation (*) we get the following equation to be proven which is more combinatorial like.

Let $r$ be an fixed integer which vary from $0\ldots n$
$$\sum_{len(\nu)=r}H^m (n+1,\nu)=\sum_{\mu\vdash n }H^{sm}(n,\mu)\binom{n-len(\mu)}{n-(len(\nu)-1)} $$
Now we can give a map from LHS that is a tuples of montonic transposition of length $(len(\nu)-1)$ which when product with a fixed cycle of lenth $n+1$ gives a cylce of type $\nu$. For example

n=3

$$H^m (4,1^4) $$
tuples are given by $(12)(23)(34)$, $(23)(13)(34)$ etc

Now we want to form the strictly monotonic tuples out of it in $S_n$ so naturally, we delete all the tuples containing $(n+1)$ and  given a series 
of tuples and given a tuples

$$(a_1,b_1) (a_2,b_2)\ldots(a_k,b_k)(a_{k+1},b_{k+1})\ldots(a_m,b_m)$$
we delete $(a_k,b_k)$ until its striclty monotonic.

For example

Now we want to make strictly monotonic tuples in $H^{sm} (3,1^3) $, $H^{sm} (3,(2,1))$, $H^{sm} (3,3)$  that is we take the tuple $(12)(23)(34)$ and delete 
$(34)$ we get strictly monotonic. For the tuple 
$(23)(13)(34)$ we delte $(34)$ and $(23)$ we get strictly monotonic.

I have checked for many cases of $n$ it holds true. it give  a bijection 
Can't prove it in general so any help appreciated.